# T-SQL error: Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm really not sure why I am receiving this error because if the Table is not there I create it and it should not go into this piece of the query if the table is there so why would it want to go into it again and try do the conversions?

This is the whole code:

```
Use test
GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('MetricsServerAudit') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN 
            CREATE TABLE  #TEMP ([TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,  [SCORECARD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PERIOD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION_TYPE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PREVIOUS_VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[UNIT] nvarchar(max) NULL)

                    BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\QPR_Logs\Audit\MetricsServerAudit.txt'
                    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\r', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPNULLS)

                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE]= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DATE],103),'/' ,'-') 
                    ALTER TABLE #TEMP ALTER COLUMN [DATE] DATE
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = '12:00:00' Where [TIME] = ''
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([TIME], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE([TIME], '/', ':')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = left([TIME], 8)
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] is null


                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit]([DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT])
                    SELECT CONCAT([DATE],'', [TIME]) AS [DateStamp], [TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT]
                    FROM #TEMP
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT [TIME] FROM [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] WHERE [TIME] = [TIME])
                    DROP TABLE #TEMP
        END

GO --SEPERATOR 
    IF (OBJECT_ID('MetricsServerAudit') IS NULL and OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NULL)
        BEGIN 
            CREATE TABLE  MetricsServerAudit ([DateStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL, [TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] date NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PERIOD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION_TYPE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PREVIOUS_VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[UNIT] nvarchar(max) NULL)
            CREATE TABLE  #TEMP ([TIME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[DATE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NULL,[USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,  [SCORECARD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ELEMENT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_IDENTIFIER] nvarchar(max) NULL,[SERIES_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PERIOD_NAME] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION_TYPE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[ACTION] nvarchar(max) NULL,[PREVIOUS_VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[VALUE] nvarchar(max) NULL,[UNIT] nvarchar(max) NULL)

                    BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\QPR_Logs\Audit\MetricsServerAudit.txt'
                    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\r', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPNULLS)

                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE]= REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),[DATE],103),'/' ,'-') 
                    ALTER TABLE #TEMP ALTER COLUMN [DATE] DATE
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = '12:00:00' Where [TIME] = ''
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([TIME], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = REPLACE([TIME], '/', ':')
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [TIME] = left([TIME], 8)
                    UPDATE #TEMP SET [DATE] = '2015-01-01' Where [DATE] is null                 


                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit]([DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT])
                    SELECT CONCAT([DATE],'', [TIME]) AS [DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER],[SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER],[ELEMENT_NAME],[SERIES_IDENTIFIER],[SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME],[ACTION_TYPE],[ACTION],[PREVIOUS_VALUE],[VALUE],[UNIT]
                    FROM #TEMP
                    DROP TABLE #TEMP

                    IF (NOT EXISTS(select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = '[DateStamp]' AND DATA_TYPE = 'DATETIME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MetricsServerAudit'))
                            BEGIN
                                UPDATE [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] SET [DateStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,(SUBSTRING([DateStamp],1,10)+' '+SUBSTRING([DateStamp],11,15)))
                                ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] ALTER COLUMN [DateStamp] DATETIME
                            END
        END
```

This is the piece where the error comes up:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MetricsServerAudit] SET [DateStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,(SUBSTRING([DateStamp],1,10)+' '+SUBSTRING([DateStamp],11,15)))
```

It's in the 4th last line of the whole code.

This is the full error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
>   Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Can anyone tell me why it does this and how to resolve it?

Comment: And is `[DateStamp]` not of type `datetime`? Error seems straightforward

Answer (score 1):

It's a compilation error. This code won't compile if MetricsServerAudit.DateStamp exists and is a datetime because substring doesn't allow datetime as its first parameter. Your options are:

1. put this code into a stored procedure so that it is only compiled once or
2. add another conversion so that you only ever pass a varchar to substring, e.g.: `CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DateStamp])..`